# Trying to create a rails model scope query for records since date x, use a lambda?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I think I will want to use combine a model level finder with a lambda.

```
named_scope :recent_snaps, lambda {|since_when| {:conditions=>{:created_at >= since_when}}}
```

but I am not sure and also if I have the syntax correct, espcially for the parameter piece and can't run the app right now to check at console.

I do not want to use a find_by_sql or a controller find, I want my finder at the model level for rspec testing.

Comment: Just a note: you can test `find_by_sql` in RSpec just as well as any other Rails `find`. I agree that it should be avoided, but your reason for doing so seems wrong.

Comment: yes.  More detail: I am trying to stick to rails finders and chainable scopes.  Also I want to try and do all my queries using one DSL where possible to maximize maintainability.

Comment: Those are much better reasons. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're on Rails 3 (as you presumably are, given the question's tags) you should be using `scope` rather than `named_scope` and `where` rather than `conditions`. Additionally, you can't use `>=` in a hash.

Your finished scope should look something like this:

```
scope :recent_snaps, lambda { |since_when| where("created_at >= ?", since_when) }
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement Alex's answer: for the looks of the query you're trying, I think you'll like [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel):

```
scope :recent_snaps, lambda { |since_when| where{created_at >= since_when} }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just other ways to achieve the same (at least in rails 3.1)

in plain rails

`scope :recent_snaps, ->(since_when) {  where("created_at >= ?", since_when) }`

rails+squeel

`scope :recent_snaps, ->(since_when) {  where{created_at >= since_when} }`